# Is there a way to view the plots from matplotlib within a docker container running on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib, ubuntu

I am attempting to work on an image segmentation task from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/hsankesara/unet-image-segmentation/data). I am running this on a docker container that I've set up on a server running in an Ubuntu console.

I'm relatively new to this, so I'm quite unsure about how to view the images produced by matplotlib within the docker container I've produced. The code just runs, and then exits - I'm left uncertain about what the outputs of the code are (as in what the filters for the CNN are) and I can't see any of the plots.

Many thanks!

Comment: Probably a matter of setting up GUI. Try something like [this](https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110)

Comment: I've had a look at this but I'm not quite sure how it works - I've done the commands it says, but when I ran it it didn't show me any GUI I don't think, and I don't quite get how to tie the docker container it discusses with my one running python

Comment: Can you include the command you used to run docker? Did you include the display flags mentioned in the link? `--volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw"`, `--env="DISPLAY"`, and `--net=host`

Comment: docker run -it --rm --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 --name=containername --env="DISPLAY" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root./Xauthority:rw" --net=host imagename

Sorry I've censored what I called the contain and its image as they have my full name

Comment: It's ok, Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can help you figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the plots as a .png or .jpg files and download it from the Ubuntu server. This will help you view the plots as image file in your local system.

you can save the plots using

`import matplotlib. some plot function as plt`
`do some plotting`
`plt.save('path to save')

An example from [Matplotlib.pyplot.savefig() in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-in-python/)

```
# importing required modules 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
# creating plotting data
xaxis =[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
yaxis =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  
# plotting 
plt.plot(xaxis, yaxis)
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
  
# saving the file.Make sure you 
# use savefig() before show().
plt.savefig("squares.png")
```

[image]

After saving this file you can simply use some client to transfer data from the server.
For FTP you can use [FileZilla Client](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php)

Hope this solves the problem!!

Comment: There's no way to get it to open as a window?

Thanks for your help! Out of interest, if I do this in docker what location will the plots be saved in

Comment: can you let me know the command you are using to start the docker container.

Comment: docker run -it --rm --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 --name=ContainerName --env="DISPLAY" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root./Xauthority:rw" --net=host ImageName

Comment: In your python script you can write a simple code to print the directory. import os;
cwd = os.getcwd(); print(cwd)